# Hover the last item of first row,first two items of second row move

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, transition

I just made a layout using bootstrap and css 2d,

```
please follow [this link to see]
```

(http://codepen.io/geesonC/pen/xGYJrQ)

The problem is when I hover the last item of first row,the first two items of the second row will move to the third row.

I just cannot solve it, please give me advice.

CSS code

```
<style>
.margintop-300{
    margin-top:-300px;
}

.rotate-imgs{
    padding:24px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:60px;
    text-align:center;
}

.rotate-imgs:hover >.rotate-img{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.rotate-imgs:hover >.rotate-img-bg1{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    border:0;
}

.rotate-imgs:hover >.rotate-img-bg2{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    border:0;
}

.rotate-img{
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-1deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-1deg);
    transform: rotate(-1deg);

    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;

    z-index:1012;
}

.rotate-img-bg1{
    padding:0;  
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #dddddd;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(6deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(6deg);
    transform: rotate(6deg);

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    z-index:1011;
}

.rotate-img-bg2{
    padding:0;  
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #dddddd;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(10deg);
    transform: rotate(10deg);

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    z-index:1010;
}
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
         <div class="rotate-imgs">
            <div class="rotate-img-bg1"><img src=""></div>
            <div class="rotate-img-bg2 margintop-300"><img src=""></div>
            <div class="rotate-img margintop-300"><img src=""></div>
         </div>
     </div>
     ...
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
         <div class="rotate-imgs">
            <div class="rotate-img-bg1"><img src=""></div>
            <div class="rotate-img-bg2 margintop-300"><img src=""></div>
            <div class="rotate-img margintop-300"><img src=""></div>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS border attributes (like on `.rotate-img-bg1` and `.rotate-img-bg2`) are outset from the element, meaning that they affect page layout. A quick solution would be instead of using `border: none;` on those elements, use `border: 1px solid transparent;` instead.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/maxlaumeister/pen/MwQBQQ